# Combining two FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS from different resources

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-fileprovider

I am using hotline.io by freshdesk. As part of SDK integration, I need to include `FileProvider` to support Android 7.0+. The issue is, I already have FileProvider defined in manifest.

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>

<!-- provider_path.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

This is the FileProvider from [hotline.io](https://support.hotline.io/support/solutions/articles/221188-hotline-android-sdk-integration-steps) SDK documentation:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="my.app.demo.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/hotline_file_provider_paths" />
</provider>

<!-- hotline_file_provider_paths -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string name="hotline_file_provider_authority">my.app.demo.provider</string>
```

Obviously there will be an error if both FileProvider are defined in manifest. Is there any way to include both resources in one provider? I have tried combining two resources like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    </paths>
    <string name="hotline_file_provider_authority">my.app.demo.provider</string>
</resources>
```

and this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <!-- I extract FileProvider.xml from the hotline.sdk and combine with local fileprovder.xml -->
    <files-path
        name="int_files"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="ext_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="int_cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="ext_cache"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

but no avail. I am still getting this error.

> "Missing/Bad FileProvider for Hotline. Camera capture will fail in devices running Nougat or later versions of OS (error code 354)"

**FIXED**

Thank to [greenapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2108972/greenapps) for pointing me out. I had wrongly configured the FileProvider. Solved it by moving `<string name="hotline_file_provider_authority">my.app.demo.provider</string>` to strings.xml.

Comment: `<string name="hotline_file_provider_authority">my.app.demo.provider</string>` Wrong. That is not from hotline_file_provider_paths.xml  but from strings.xml. Look at the docu from the link you provided.

Comment: You can have as many FileProfiders in your app as long as android:authorities are different and android:resource. I even think that android:resource can point to the same xml file. Didn't they show an example hotline_file_provider_paths.xml  file?

Comment: i am having same issue. @greenapps - i am adding two providers in manifest with different resource and authorities. but i am getting      error:     Element provider#android.support.v4.content.FileProvider at AndroidManifest.xml:339:9-347:20 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @amad-yus , can you please post complete android manifect and file_path.xml for file provider which you have combined. i need to implement is in my project. It would be big help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Moving provider string to String.xml file removes issue of file provider of Camara (solves this error). But in case of multiple Product flavor, this solution does not work.

Surprisingly, there is no way we can resolve this error with multiple product flavor as Strings.xml file can not access values from Gradle variables, and moving somewhere else the file-provider-authority creates this error.

Bad solutions from Google Android , before thinking, they come with solutions. {Because problem is, multiple product flavor can not be installed on same device because of this limitation..!!? }

---- FIXED ---

You can create directory structure based on Product flavor, where different string values can be given based on Flavor. This is best solution.